# Select filtering and applying quantity amount to listed percentages

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I tried to search but didn't find anything that was exact to what I was looking for. Let's say that I have the Investment$$ and I want to allocate that amount to only Items = to Toy Story and where Character begins with TS. The Investment $$ should only be applied to "Toy Story" and where character begins with "TS".

Apologies on not being able to embed the pictorial example to this message.

I need to write this in VBA. My questions is, is the best way to do this through a vlookup (programmed via VBA)? I want to avoid having the $1000 applied to the wrong movie title and even when it is applied to the right one (Toy Story) I want to make sure it's applied to the right ("TS") ones.

I'll also experiment on my end as well.

[Pixar Movie Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxfvz.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Answer (score 0):

No need for VBA here. You can go with a plain vanilla Excel formula.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote you, but as it stands this answer isn't very sufficient and would stand better as a comment instead. Perhaps you could provide more insight?

Comment: I think he's saying just use a "vlookup" in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

What you need in this situation is a key/ID item for your `VLOOKUP` - how you make that key is up to you, but with it you can easily utilize `VLOOKUP`. See my below example:

[image]